# AWS lambda- how to make the bot say a specific answer to the user using AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm really new to AWS Lex and AWS Lambda.
I'm trying to send a response message to the user when he inserted an invalid slot value.
I want the bot to write to the user "We do not have such type of bikes, the popular types are Men/Women/Unisex/Kids."

But it throws this error instead:

> An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received invalid response from Lambda: Can not construct instance of IntentResponse, problem: The validated object is null at [Source: {"isValid": false, "violatedSlot": "BikeType", "message": {"contentType": "PlainText", "content": "We do not have such type of bikes, the popular types are Men/Women/Unisex/Kids."}}; line: 1, column: 181]

The lambda function that creates the response:

```
def build_validation_result(is_valid, violated_slot, message_content):
    if message_content is None:
        return {
            "isValid": is_valid,
            "violatedSlot": violated_slot,
        }

    return {
        'isValid': is_valid,
        'violatedSlot': violated_slot,
        'message': {'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': message_content}
    }
```

How should I fix the format to match AWS lambda response?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lex has a particular format for responses see <
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html>](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html%3E)

But yours might look something like this

```
    message={"dialogAction": {  
    "type": "Close",  
    "fulfillmentState":   "Failed",  
    "message": {  
      "contentType": "PlainText",  
      "content": "We do not have such type of bikes, the popular types are Men/Women/Unisex/Kids."  
    }}
return message
```